# Why the conflicts are always with merging branches?

Tags: git

I'm learning the concepts of Git, I was testing some commands to understand how Git works.

I created a remote repository on my Github and cloned it.

To test merging between branches ran command:

```
git checkout -b add_Bob
```

This line was to create my new branch. Then changed my Bob.txt file, then committed the changes :

```
git checkout master
```

However, I changed the same line on the same file on the master branch. I then merged the "add_Bob" branch to my "master branch" :

```
git merge add_Bob
```

It showed a conflict on the Bob.txt file like this :

```
Auto-merging Bob.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Bob.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Why these conflicts are showing ?

Comment: Did you look at `Bob.txt`?  It'll have conflict markers that will tell you exactly why the automatic merge failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge conflicts happen because you've modified the same line(s) in your branches.

To fix it open `Bob.txt` your favorite editor and search for these characters: `<<<<<<< HEAD`. `=======` divides your changes from the branches which is followed by `>>>>>>> name of the branch`

If you want to keep only your branch's changes remove the markers and make the appropriate modification.

After resolving merge conflicts stage and commit your changes.

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
```